# Partial Spring JPA transaction rollback

Tags: java, jpa, spring-data-jpa, spring-transactions, rollback

I have a spring boot application that connects with two databases simultaneously. I read the data from the first database proceed with processing and then write other data to a second database.
However, in my service I have a problem with rollback in case of exception during processing. Rollback only first database and not second too.

This is code in my service

```java
@Service
public class Service {

    @Transactional(transactionManager = "firstDatabase", rollbackFor = Exception.class)
    public void methodA() {
        InObjectEntity object = repositoryIN.findObject(); // TABLE_1
        object.setProcessed("Y");
        repository.save(object);
        methodB(object);
    }

    @Transactional(transactionManager = "secondDatabase", rollbackFor = Exception.class)
    public void methodB(InObjectEntity in) {
        OutObjectEntity out = new OutObjectEntity(); // TABLE_2
        out.setValue(object.getValue());
        methodC();
        repositoryOUT.save(out);
        // exeception raised here!!!!!
        throw new Exception();
    }

    private void methodC() {
        AnotherObjectEntity another = new AnotherObjectEntity(); // TABLE_3
        another.setValue("new value");
        repositoryOUT.save(another);
    }
}
```

When exception is raised records in TABLE_2 and TABLE_3 are stored/changed anyway but record in TABLE_1 is not stored/changed (execute rollback).

Did I do something wrong?

Comment: One transaction manager needs to oversee both databases.  If not, what's the point of transaction management?

Comment: If I don't indicate the name for transactionManager I get error: NoUniqueBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type ... when starting application

Comment: You have to give it a transaction manager bean name, but there should only be one.

Comment: Ok, thank you so much for your time.